# What's Template composite in Gtk

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying understand the Gtk **Composite Template** concept. But I not found enough information.
Is **Composite Template** a way to mix `glade code` and eg, `python code` to build a gtk component class?

Where I can find a documentation about it? Python3 examples would be good.

Comment: Composite Templates are not yet available for python. There is an open bug for it [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701843).